# Import SVG vs. Require SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg, importerror

I'm working on a React project, and creating a component called SVGLogo that simply imports an svg and exports as a component. I noticed that when I use require() to import my svg file, it works fine:

```
const SVGLogo = require('../../../../../vft-site/src/images/logo.svg');
```

But my linter suggests I use the import statement. I changed it but now I get the error 'cannot find module... or its corresponding type declarations':

```
import SVGLogo from '../../../../../vft-site/src/images/logo.svg';
```

Why are these different?

Answer (score 0):

import comes in es6 like a new feature and require can be called from anywhere but import can be called on top of script